# How to unit test Laravel application without ability to migrate tables because migrations are handled by another application

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, laravel-5

I've recently pointed an existing laravel project to use a new postgres DB. The new postgres DB is maintained by a Rails API application that does all the migrations for it.

My question is with this setup, what is the best way to Unit test the laravel project. Currently all the existing unit tests are broken as they all saved to the DB with the use of

```
use DatabaseMigrations;
```

The Laravel application will not be doing migrations anymore, but is still directly accesses the DB and is not currently going through the Rails api to access the data.

Should I mock out the DB requests in my unit tests?

or

Since I can still run unit tests that hit the DB if the postgres test database is already migrated with the tables ( via the rails application migrating the test DB), is there a way to empty the DB after running the unit test *without* the ability drop and migrate the tables? Could I use transactions somehow and rollback all the transactions I've done in a specific unit test?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

So I believe I've figured it out. I had the right idea for using Transactions instead of Migrations for unit tests.

In the Laravel test classes, instead of using

```
use DatabaseMigrations;
```

You can use

```
use DatabaseTransactions;
```

This will use the current tables that are in your DB. In my case, I point my tests to use specific DB that I have setup for testing called 'my_project_test' ( assuming the regular app DB would be called 'my_project') where I have already migrated/created the tables. Once the test completes it will "rollback"/revert any data that you have inserted or removed from the DB to bring it back to its previous state. Asserts should act the same if you are using DatabaseMigrations or DatabaseTranactions. Just have to ensure that your test DB is fully up to date with its migrations.

Example of what the class would look like...

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Illuminate\Routing\Route;

class UserControllerTest extends TestCase
{   
    //Instead of DatabaseMigrations use DatabaseTransactions instead.
    //use DatabaseMigrations; 
    use DatabaseTransactions;

   ... unit tests for class
 }
```

Comment: Yes, it works, i had config my phpunitxml too, with the name of my database instead of :memory: